# Plotting time on X axis in excel

Tags: excel, graph, plot

I have done **24 hour** measurement and results obtain contains around 1400 entries. Now I want to plot those results in such a way

- That x axis represent my time and y axis the corresponding value.
- My x axis should be divided into 24 sections each representing 1
  hour.
- My exact start time is **14:00** and end time is **next day 14:00**.

For more clarification I am adding a simple version of my data here below
[image: Data table]

And resulting Plot I am getting is this.[image: Plot]

I look forward to your answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the time values go across midnight, you need to add a date part to the time value, so they can be plotted correctly as before and after midnight. At the very least, the time values for the first day should have a 0 before the decimal, e.g. 0.875 for 9 pm, and the values after midnight should have a 1 before the decimal, e.g. 1.125 for 1 am, so it falls on the next day and not the same day as the 9pm value.

Then plot an XY Scatter chart.

Work out what Excel's internal number (date/time value showing in General format) is for the desired X axis minimum, maximum and major/minor increments and format the x axis accordingly. Set the number format to hh:mm

Edit: For example: you want the minimum X axis value to be 24-Dec-2015 11 pm. Write that into a cell as a date/time. Format the cell to General. Then use the number you see in the format dialog for the X axis minimum.

If you want the major unit to be 1 hour, write the time value 1:00 into a cell and format it with general. Use that number in the dialog for Major.

Format the X axis labels to show time values, not dates.

[image]

Comment: I have inserted now my simplfied values and resulting graphs. I have now taken only 24 values each corresponding to 1 hour (my actual data has 1441 entries each corresponding to 1 minute). Now i tried to adjust the x axis but still I am not able to adjust it according to the time stamp given. Do you have any clue regarding this? Thank you

Comment: I added some explanation. By the way, you can plot more than 24 values. The above is only needed to get the X axis showing correctly. You can have data for every second, if you want to.

Comment: Yes Now I have reached the point to get my x axis as i want. But there one problem I am facing now there is no graph plotted on y axis when I did this. What wrong i did. any idea please?

Comment: You need to make sure that the X axis is in the range of your actual data values. What is the date range in your data? What is the date range for the X axis? They need to overlap.

Comment: Oh yes I got that there was an internal error. Thank you for your kind help